# gets inside a separate void function not working

Tags: c

I'm trying to get the `gets()` function to work on a given string. Everything else works properly up to this point.

```
 char nads[100];

   gets(nads);
   printf("%s", nads);
```

The rest of the code follows, but I can't see why it would cause an issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>

void problema_1 (void);
void problema_2 (void);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese_Brazil");

    INICIO: printf("Para visualizar as respostas dos desafios, digite o número do mesmo : ");
    int problema;
    scanf("%i", &problema);
    if (problema==1)
        {
            problema_1();
        }
    else if (problema==2)
        {
            problema_2();
        }
    else
        {
            printf("Escolha um valor válido e reinicie\n");
            goto INICIO;
        }
    return 0;
}

void problema_1(void)
{    
   char nads[100];

   gets(nads);
   printf("%s", nads);    
}

void problema_2(void)
{
    printf("Resolução problema 2");
    FILE *matriz;

    matriz = fopen("matriz.txt", "r");
}
```

Comment: How do you know it does not work?

Comment: [Why `gets()` is too dangerous to be used — ever!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used).

Comment: Note that `problema_2()` leaks the file stream it opens.  How have you determined that it doesn't work?  You should have shown that in the question.  If you'd entered `1 elephant` as the first input, you'd see what's going on.

Comment: Well, it runs everything but the {gets()}. It might be the compiler, but turning it off and on againd didn't work. If i get the function {problema_1} and run it as a main(), it works.

Comment: I can't find the issue